# Crystal report error

Tags: crystal-reports

I am developing a win application ( in .net 2005 ) in which i have to use crystal reports. But now it generates crystal query engine. Then I have to reinstall .net. Is there any workaround for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the version of Crystal Reports you are using, but you might make sure that crqe.dll is properly registered on your machine by using regsvr32.  Also, if you ever had a previous version of Crystal Reports on this computer, the problem could also stem from conflicting DLL version.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for ur reply. I am using crystal reports with .net 2005 [ sorry i don't know the version number]. Yes, there was a previous version of crystal report in my system. How could i avoid the DLL conflict?

Comment: Are you just using the crystal runtime environment (CRAXDRT) or do you have the actual report designer installed?